# Laravel pagination Relation with API resources

Tags: php, laravel

I have user resource as follow:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'posts' => PostResource::collection($this->posts()->paginate(10)),
    ];
}
```

In User model, there is hasMany relation `posts`

My problem with paginating, the links and meta of post paginate does not show just get 10 posts without links of paginate

My controller

```
$user = User::query()
    ->where('id', $userId)
    ->with('posts')
    ->firstOrFail();

return new UserResource($user);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel doesn't handle this case for you.

You have just 2 options:

1. Write a custom pagination logic
2. Just use two different API's with dedicated pagination in the posts API (recommended)

Comment: Is there any way to make a chain of multi-resource to single one?!

Comment: The point is that you can implement anything by yourself, but it would be a custom solution that doesn't  reflect any standard api specs such as jsonapi.

The best thing to do in this case is to just follow a standard convention and implement 2 different API's.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you return the `posts` attribute as a collection not pagination.

Try

```
return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'posts' => $this->posts()->paginate(10),
    ];
```